# How often does an enhancement bonus add damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage

If I had a +2 longsword & I used a 3[W] power, would I add the +2 once, or three times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Once.**

Magic item entries have an **Enhancement** line. For a sword, this line would say "Attack rolls and damage rolls".

The *Rules Compendium* has a section that describes reading a magic item entry. In the 'Enhancement' section, on page 280, it says that:

> For items that give an enhancement bonus, this entry specifies what that bonus applies to: AC, other defenses, or attack rolls and damage rolls.

This means that the sword's enhancement bonus is a "bonus to a damage roll".

The *Rules Compendium* addresses this type of bonus in the section "Modifiers on Damage Rolls", on page 222:

> Many powers, feats, and other game features grant bonuses or penalties to damage rolls. A bonus to a damage roll is added to the damage roll as a whole, not to each die roll within it.
>
> *Example:* A warlock has a +4 bonus to damage rolls. If that warlock uses an attack power that deals 2d10 damage, the warlock adds 4 to the total of the two d10s. He does not add 4 to each d10.